# Pegar informação do usuário e checar se domínio está disponível

Tags: php, html

Quero fazer um código em que ele verifica a informação do usuário e vê se o domínio existe. Porém, não retorna absolutamente nada.

HTML:

```
 <form action="teste.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName2">WWW</label>
            <input type="text" class="p-3 form-control form-control-lg mb-2 mr-sm-2 input-ro" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="www." readonly>

      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2">Domínio</label>
      <div class="input-group justify-content-center mb-2 mr-sm-2">
            <input type="text" name="dominio" class="input-dom form-control form-control-lg" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2" placeholder="Digite o domínio desejado">
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 select-padding">
           <select name="com" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                   <option>.com</option>
                   <option>.com.br</option>
                   <option>.net</option>
           </select>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dominio btn-outline-danger">
               <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
       </button>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
 <?
require "registro-de-dominios.php";

$dominio = $_POST['dominio'];
function dominio_disponivel($dominio){
 if(checkdnsrr($dominio, 'ANY') && gethostbyname($dominio) != $dominio)
        echo "<p>Domínio <b>disponível.</b></p>";
    else
        echo "<p>Domínio <b>indisponível.</b></p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Pelo o que parece, no teu html não existe nenhum atributo name aos seus inputs, o método POST recupera o valor de acordo com os names dos inputs.

Comment: Eu coloquei o atributo name="dominio" no segundo input, também coloquei no select, mas no php chamei apenas o dominio.

Comment: Então provavelmente o problema deve tá nesse arquivo `registro-de-dominios.php`

Comment: Não sei. O engraçado é que se eu colocar `if(dominio_disponivel('zerobugs.com.br'))
  echo "<p>Domínio zerobugs.com.br <b>disponível.</b></p>";
else
  echo "<p>Domínio zerobugs.com.br <b>indisponível.</b></p>";
if(dominio_disponivel('zerobugs-asd.com.br'))
  echo "<p>Domínio zerobugs-asd.com.br <b>disponível.</b></p>";
else
  echo "<p>Domínio zerobugs-asd.com.br <b>indisponível.</b></p>"; ` fora da função, dentro do php, irá me retornar os dois ```echos```.

Comment: Onde que é chamado sua função `dominio_disponivel` ?

Comment: De acordo com seu php, você não chama a função `dominio_disponivel `. Você pode chamar logo após  essa linha `$dominio = $_POST['dominio'];`  a função `dominio_disponivel($dominio)`

Comment: Acabei de testar isto. Você estava certo, é algum erro no HTML, pois não atribui o atributo `name` no `form`.

Comment: Eu vi o atributo `name="dominio"` no segundo input

Comment: Eu chamei a função, no final do PHP eu coloquei `dominio_disponivel($dominio)`, porém, quando vou testar, aparece apenas domínios indisponíveis. Mesmo colocando um domínio que está disponível, ele vai no else.

Comment: Você está concatenando o valor de domínio com o select de name `com`? Como está sua função `checkdnsrr `?